# Redirect Apache just for specific site

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, proxy, proxypass

is it possible to have a redirect for a specific URL. I mean the following.

Redirect to an other site. On this site there are images under http://www.examples/images

```
ProxyPass /content http://www.example/content
ProxyPassReverse /content http://www.example/content
```

But images are not loading, so I try to add.

```
ProxyPass /images http://www.example/images
```

But there are also images on the proxy under http://www.proxy.com/images where I try to redirect.

So it is possible to redirect the images just for the example.com site when they needed?

I hope somebdy understand what I mean :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly rather than a ProxyPass you need to use mod_rewrite. You can set a rewrite condition such that when the requested resource does not exist as a file a rewrite rule with a proxy target gets triggered. This answer might apply http://serverfault.com/a/656001/37681

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Redirect`directive in *mod_alias*, see the documentation [here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

This should help you:

```
# Redirect to a URL on a different host
Redirect "/content" "http://www.example/content"
```

Comment: Hi, the simple redirect is working, but when I type http://www.myproxy/content/test/, I get an redirect to http://www.example/content.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to use just the exact path? So when I type http://www.myproxy.com/content/ I want the redirect but when I type http://www.myproxy.com/content/test/test/test I do not want a redirect.

Comment: RedirectMatch will set you up. Please take a look at the documentation i linked before further inquiry.

Comment: RedirectMatch "^/Images/(.*)" "http://new.example.com/Images/$1"
I add this one for my images, but is doesnt work.
What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link a specific URL pattern to another site, then this question has been answered here using `mod_rewrite` instead of `ProxyPass` : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701992/1725739

Comment: Consider mod_alias with redirect instead. Also see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried an other solution so far.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myproxy.com/content/$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ htpp://www.example.de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

But everything is redirect to www.example.com
How can I change this?